# How to implement ioc for Automapper (IMappingEngine) using Unity in webapi project

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, unity-container, automapper

I am developing webapi project and extensively using Automapper to map objects.
Currently i am using Mapper.Map

Can anyone direct me how to implement this? How to call this configure method while registering IMappingEngine in Unity?

My current automapper mapping:

```
public static class AutomapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve(type));

            cfg.CreateMap<Logger, Log>()
                  .ForMember(d => d.TxId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AsRunTxIdValueResolver>());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use automapper profiles to create various mappers and register all  profiles like this:

```
public static class AutomapperConfiguration
{
    public static MapperConfiguration MyMapperConfiguration;
    public static void Configure()
    {
        MyMapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            var types = typeof(Program).Assembly.GetTypes();
            var profiles = types.Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Profile)))
                                .Select(Activator.CreateInstance)
                                .OfType<Profile>()
                                .ToList();
            profiles.Each(p => cfg.AddProfile(p));
        });

        MapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();       
    }
}
```

Your automapper profile class will look like this:

```
public class LoggerProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Logger,Log>()
          .ForMember(d => d.TxId, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<AsRunTxIdValueResolver>());
    }
}
```

In your startup.cs, you would have to register the mappers like this:

```
AutoMapperConfiguration.RegisterMappers();
```

Comment: How do use it as with dependency injection? There used to be an IMappingEngine once